# Patch (SUPEE-6285) 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED saving rejects cart.phtml

Tags: security, patches, supee-6285

```
sh PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh 
PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: 24: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: 24: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: 29: 0: not found
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
-e ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/Mage.php
patching file app/code/community/Phoenix/Moneybookers/controllers/MoneybookersController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/AjaxController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Category/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/DatafeedsController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/ReviewController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Block/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Page/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/PageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/WysiwygController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Customer/System/Config/ValidatevatController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/JsonController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/NotificationController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/CustomerController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ProductController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ReviewController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/SalesController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ShopcartController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/TagController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/ReportController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/CatalogController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/OrderController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Billing/AgreementController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/View/GiftmessageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Recurring/ProfileController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/TransactionsController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Config/System/StorageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TagController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Tax/RateController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TaxController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Api2/controllers/Adminhtml/Api2/AttributeController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/controllers/Adminhtml/Bundle/SelectionController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/controllers/Adminhtml/RefreshController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/controllers/Adminhtml/Centinel/IndexController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Connect/controllers/Adminhtml/Extension/LocalController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/controllers/Adminhtml/Paygate/Authorizenet/PaymentController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/Adminhtml/Paypal/ReportsController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/CatalogController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/OrderController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Block/Adminhtml/Widget/Chooser.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/controllers/Adminhtml/WidgetController.php
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/failure.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/email/rss.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 97.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml.rej
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
patching file downloader/Maged/.htaccess
patching file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
patching file downloader/lib/.htaccess
patching file downloader/template/connect/packages.phtml
patching file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
patching file downloader/template/login.phtml
patching file downloader/template/settings.phtml
patching file errors/processor.php
```

Answer (score 1):

The patch failed because it couldn't modify the file. It looks like its a template so it is more than likely because it has been changed.

Look at the patch file and find where the problem file is referenced and comment out that patch. Now run the patch file again it should apply.

Now you should try and manually apply the patch lines to the template if they still exist in the template file.

Comment: Let's replace "probably want to" with "have to" , otherwise you leave your site vulnerable

Comment: @fschmengler, good point I have edited my answer. Worth noting though that the patch may no longer be relevant if the template has been changed significantly

Comment: And also, find cart.html in your template you are using and manually patch that!!! Otherwise you leave your customers open to a nasty XSS hole.

Comment: Thanks guys, @FiascoLabs, How to manually patch this file?

Comment: @ismo Look at the lines you commented out. Try and find those lines in the same file in your theme. Manually change those lines with the changes that the patch is attempting to make.

Answer (score -1):

finaly,to resolve this problem, comment the 2 lines below in the file PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v1-2015-07-10-08-10-09.sh:

--- app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml
+++ app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml

thanks